# Passing data to a custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift

ViewControllerA will be pushing to ViewControllerB. ViewcontrollerB is a `UITableView` that has a custom `UITableViewCell` that is registered upon load.

Here is my custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    // Here is me attempting to pass my data from my view controller
    someButton.text = stringFromViewController
}
```

Here's my `UITableView`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let customCell = CustomCell()
    customCell.stringFromViewController = "Some Text"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB", sender: nil)    
}
```

Whenever I attempt this the `string` comes back as empty. I'm not sure if this has to do with the fact that I am trying to pass this data to the `UITableViewCell` instead of the `UITableView` that contains the custom `cell`. I'd like to pass the data to my custom `cell` class.

Comment: I dont see any reference to the table datasource in your question. Can you add more code about your tableView?

Answer (score 1):

You going about this the wrong way.
your tableView is reloading automatically upon loading controller B.
you should pass the data to the cell in `tableView:CellForRow:` method.
you can also call tableView.reloadData() once you assign the value from controller A.
here's an example:

```
class ControllerB {
  var tableView: UITableView! //IBOutlet?
  var stringFromA: String? {
      didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell")
    cell.stringFromA = self.stringFromA
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I should have added that there are some custom methods in uitableviewcell class that handle some constraints. I can access those from cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: You should probably handle the cell's layout and design updates in the cell's custom class and not in the viewController's, it's just makes more sense of keeping MVC architecture. You have a few methods in the cell's class (of UIView) you can override: awakeFromNib(), layoutSubview(), didMoveToSuperview(), each with its own advantages

Answer (score 0):

Because `awakeFromNib()` initilizes even before you initilize the `cell`.

instead of assigning it in this method use this in  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
let customCell = CustomCell()

customCell.someButton.setText("Some Text", forState: .Normal)

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB", sender: nil)
```

Comment: Okay, let's say that I wanted to pass a boolean value that will be used in awakeFromNib()? How would that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that clicking on a row from `View Controller A` will push `View Controller B` and you want to pass some data to the custom cell in `View Controller B`. you have to use `prepareForSegue` to pass the data.

in view controller b, set a variable, and in your case, a bool.

```
class ViewControllerB {

var boolValue: Bool?

}
```

then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in `ViewControllerA` you perform the segue

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB", sender: nil)    
}
```

Then you have to perform `prepareForSegue` according to the row being selected

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "ViewControllerB" {
        //if you need to know which row is select, use indexPath.row
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerB
            //send the details that you want, i.e
            if indexPath.row < 5 {
                controller.boolValue = true
            } else {
                controller.boolValue = false
            }
        }
    }
```

once the segue is called, you pass the data through `prepareForSegue`, then you can pass the information to the cell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        //pass the boolValue from viewcontrollerB to anotherBoolValue in custom cell
        cell.anotherBoolValue = boolValue

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The properties that I trying to access are not in ViewController B, but their in my Custom Table View Cell.

Comment: yes. so you pass it from viewcontroller b to the custom cell through the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. or perhaps you can be clearer with you question, stating the variables, what you are naming the variables and where it is so that it is easier to help you

Comment: I have added in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. this is assuming you already created a class for the custom cell with the variable `anotherBoolValue` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  [@Lirik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674561/2751762)

have a property observer on you controllerB's property and reload the table view, then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath(::)`
cast the dequeued cell to your custom cell type so that you can access all the function of your cell

`let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell") as! CustomCell`

`cell.someBotton.text = stringFromViewControllerA`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Lirik

have a property observer on you controllerB and reload the table view, then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath(::)`

cast the dequeued cell to your custom cell type so that you can access all the function of your cell

`let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell") as! CustomCell`